# Functorial and exact extensions of coherent sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Given an affine morphism that is also an open immersion $i:U\hookrightarrow X$ of Noetherian schemes and a coherent $O_U$-module $M$, $i_*M$ is quasi-coherent such that $i^*i_*M\cong M$. This implies that there is some coherent sub-sheaf of $i_*M$ that restricts to $M$ on $U$. My question is, is it possible to construct a functorial assignment $F(M)$, such that $F(M)$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ where $i^*F(M)\cong M$ and the functor $F$ is exact?

My second question is whether it is possible to extend a vector bundle to another vector bundle? (In the above paragraph can we choose the coherent sub-sheaf of $i_*M$ to be a vector bundle if we know that $M$ is a vector bundle.)

Comment: This seems unlikely. There is always the map on Grothendieck groups $K_0(X) \rightarrow K_0(U)$ given by $M \mapsto i^*M$, and the existence of extensions of coherent sheaves guarantees that this map is surjective. On the other hand, an exact functorial extension would imply the stronger condition that the map $K_0(X) \rightarrow K_0(U)$ has a section, which won't be the case e.g. if $K_0(U)$ contains more torsion than $K_0(X)$. (Of course, then the harder part is to actually find such pair $U \subseteq X$ as a counterexample).

Comment: Your second question has been [answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22111/extending-vector-bundles-on-a-given-open-subscheme). It may have been better to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Right, but the counter-examples there have the property that the complement of the open set is codimension greater than or equal to 2. Therefore the inclusion of the open set is not an affine morphism.